# SAP HANA split table with column, seperated by | into table with new rows

Tags: hana

I have a table with row, name and EUM (End users markets) as column (marked as big yellow 1 in the screenshot below).

I would like to split this table into a new one (marked as big yellow 2).
Column `#` is 1 / count(NAME)

[image: Screenshot of the table]

But I don't know how.
I found some functions with table as result,
but I can't use this function in a select or create table.

I am grateful for all suggestions.

Holger

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty table then use cursor for split and insert available rows. You can prepare dynmanic sql for inserting values, with using string replace operation.

dynamic sql: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3435270
cursor:http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/9d/3b637a5d6d44f288edb2bde73b95cc/content.htm?frameset=/en/c5/9af8fa9ece40f4ba202e12fdacdfdf/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ed/4f384562ce4861b48e22a8be3171e5/plain.htm&node_id=109